# Как вернуть пользователя на предыдущую страницу с той же позиции (Скролл) ? Spring + JS

Tags: javascript, java, веб-программирование, spring

У меня есть страница с перечнем продуктов, которые можно добавить в корзину. При добавлении продукта в корзину - контроллер возвращает пользователя на прежнюю страницу, но всегда с самого начала страницы. Как я могу запомнить прежнюю позицию пользователя на странице(скролл) ? (Сам я на данный момент слаб в JS). Знаю только способ с внутренними ссылками HTML, но это не совсем то.
Контроллер -

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cart")
public class CartController extends MenuOptions{

    private ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    public CartController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/add/{id}")
    public String addProductToCart(@PathVariable long id, HttpSession session,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Model model) {
        if (session.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
            List<Item> cart = new ArrayList<>();
            cart.add(new Item(productService.getProductById(id), 1));
            session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        } else {
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>) session.getAttribute("cart");
            int index = isExist(id, cart);
            if (index == -1) {
                cart.add(new Item(productService.getProductById(id), 1));
            } else {
                int quantity = cart.get(index).getQuantity() + 1;
                cart.get(index).setQuantity(quantity);
            }
            session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        }
        String lastPage = request.getHeader("Referer");
        return "redirect:" + lastPage;
    }

    private int isExist(long id, List<Item> cart) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
            if (cart.get(i).getProduct().getId() == id) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом решении я использовал Jquery cookie, которые создают куки с отступом от верхней границы. Когда пользователь возвращается на эту страницу - куки передает ему этот отступ и перематывает пользователя на нужную позицию.
Пример -

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            //время работы куки 10 сек
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10 * 1000));
            
            //Проверяем куки
            var scrolled = $.cookie("scrollmenu");
            if (scrolled) {
                $(window).scrollTop(scrolled);
            }

            //Создаем куки
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                $.removeCookie("scrollmenu");
                var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
                $.cookie("scrollmenu", scrolled , {expires : date});
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете возвращать из контроллера DTO примерно такого вида:

```
@Value
public class Dto {

    List<Object> objects;

    int totalCount;

    int pageNum;
}
```

Нужные вам объекты кладёте в `objects`. Свойство `totalCount` нужно для того, чтобы правильно делать пагинацию. В `pageNum` лежит страница, к которой относится возвращаемый DTO. Вы парсите всё это на фронте, и все данные у вас на руках.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но я не совсем ясно выразился. Меня интересует возможность сохранять предыдущую страницу с позицией скрола (чтоб не мотать страницу каждый раз когда добавляешь новый товар). Надеюсь так ясно выразился.

Comment: @SnejOK понял. Увы, не знаю.

Comment: @SnejOK кстати. А вы не можете использовать тот же подход? При помощи js вычисляете, сколько пользователь прокрутил и передаёте на сервер. А потом сервер вернёт это значение, когда товар будет добавлен в корзину.

Comment: Да я долго думал как сделать лучше, но в итоге пришел к jquery cookie. Я записываю в cookie на 5 секунд расстояние от верхней границы, когда пользователь попадает в контроллер (добавить в корзину)-  его сразу кидает обратно на прежнюю страницу, где jquery проверяет есть ли у него cookie, если есть - отматывает его на прежнюю позицию. И чтоб все это прикрыть - добавил на экран загрузку. Не знаю на сколько это эффективный подход, но пока работает )

Comment: @SnejOK я думаю, этот вариант лучше, чем мой. Кука для таких вещей вроде бы и предназначена) Можно даже хранить эти данные в sessionStorage, тогда они сотрутся, когда пользователь закроет вкладку, ведь эти данные временные, а с кукой пользователь может вернуться через какое-то время и у него будет значение скролла стоять. Рекомендую вам оформить своё решение как ответ, это может помочь другим людям.